# Finding the crack tip location or crack path coordinate of a ANSYS Mechanical APDL simulation

Tags: ansys, ansys-apdl

I am dealing with a crack simulation using ANSYS APDL mechanical.
For some purpose, I need to extract the location of crack tip under every substep of simulation. The simulation was done by 2D XFEM method.
Is there any commands to find the crack tip under every substep of simulation?

I have done some research on forum and journal papers, however I cannot found any method to fulfill my purpose.
So far, I have found the stress and the displacement of each node under every substep.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

please see the Mechanical APDL help on the *GET command. You can use that to get the node number at the tip of the crack, then from there its as-modeled location and displacement.
Mike